# how to keep html tags and escape < > in string in javascript or c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, regex

I have a string in javascript which i want to print in excel file using c# code.
My javascript string variable is like :

```
var abc = "<span style=white-space:pre> (StartTime < '2015-05-01 06:00:00' and StopTime > '2015-01-01 06:00:00')</span>";
```

And I am using regex to show content in between the html tags. Like shown below:

```
var regX = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
abc = abc.replace(regX, "");
```

I just wanted to show below output:

```
(StartTime < '2015-05-01 06:00:00' and StopTime > '2015-01-01 06:00:00')
```

But above regex is making < > as a tag and hence output that shows me is:

```
(StartTime  '2015-01-01 06:00:00')
```

If anybody have solution to this then please help me.

If anybody have solution to get required output using regex in c# code then he may also tell his solution as in the end i need this string in c# code so no matters where i m handling it.

Comment: If you know that the '<>' characters you want to keep will always be surrounded by spaces and the '<>' characters in your html tags will not be, you could use that fact in your regex.

Comment: I m not sure if <> will always be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: what if you replace <> with strings :'lt','gt' and after you remove the HTML, you can do a replace of lt, gt with their corresponding operations

Comment: Actually the issue is the original string. From where I see it HTML should reside in HTML file/template, not in string variables. In this example, the data is `StartTime < '2015-05-01 06:00:00' and StopTime > '2015-01-01 06:00:00'`, the rest depends on how you display/use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = "<span style=white-space:pre> (StartTime < '2015-05-01 06:00:00' and StopTime > '2015-01-01 06:00:00')</span>"
```

This variable contains buggy HTML. If you can fix the source of the bug so that it contains valid HTML like:

```
var abc = "<span style=white-space:pre> (StartTime &lt; '2015-05-01 06:00:00' and StopTime > '2015-01-01 06:00:00')</span>";
```

Then life will be much easier.

Otherwise if you can be sure that the `<` you want to preserve will always be followed by a space you could use the regex:

```
/(<\w([^>]+)>)/g
```

Slightly safer is:

```
/(<\[a-z]([^>]+)>)/ig
```

Which will look for `<` followed by a letter in the A–Z range, as per all HTML elements. There are still cases where realistic use of `<` in the text will look like a tag though, so fixing the initial bug is still a better approach.

Comment: The fact he is using this string in excel would indicate that HTML entities are a bad choice though, although this doesn't solve the problem... The original issue is actually having html in a variable which should only contain text to be presented differently depending on the target device. Long story short, html should be added around the variable when rendering in a browser, not removed when not in a browser, especially as the question shows it's not such an easy job...

Comment: @Bartdude HTML entities aren't a bad choice for the initial string, which appears to be a chunk of buggy HTML. HTML entities would be a bad choice for a subsequent use in Excel, but then they should be removed when used with Excel.

Comment: HTML is not a data-storage format. Those HTML entities and HTML tags are just useless/disruptive when used outside a browser and shouldn't actually be stored cause that calls for future issues : when data is to be used somewhere else (this example), when somehow the HTML needs to be changed, ... I agree though that using entities would help solving this problem, but while he's changing code generating this variable, he might aswell just remove any HTML from this string and add it when it has to be displayed in a browser. At least that's how I see it...

Comment: @Bartdude depends on why he has some buggy HTML to begin with. It should be non-buggy something. Whether non-buggy plain text or non-buggy HTML could depend on other things.

Comment: This is just text, that's it, it's no buggy HTML or so. `<` and `>` are (unicode) characters like others, they just have a special meaning in some contexts and should then be escaped somehow in those contexts. If there was no HTML at all in this variable in the first place, OP wouldn't even had to ask the question, he could use this variable as the string it represents, as long as he uses UTF-8 of course. My point is this is buggy HTML only because this string is actually formatted as HTML, remove the `span` and it's just a correct string usable anywhere...